# How to start a number column from a specific number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to generate a unique incrementing number that will be part of a more complex invoice number. I would like to keep the increment logic in the app.

I must resume the numbering that is currently going on another system.

I intend to do `Model.maximum(:custom_number).next`

But how can I start the `custom_number` column from a given number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you just need to reset the index of the primary key of your table (Model) to the number that you want.

If your are using MySQL or PostgreSQL then:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_id_seq RESTART WITH 1453;
```

then the next record will have for index in this case the 1453

For access the DB console just run on your console **rails db**

EDIT

```
before_filter :check_invoice_number 
def check_invoice_number
  self.invoice_column = Model.last.invoice_column + 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm not using the id column here, but an `invoice_number` column. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Well, for SQL databases you can only have one auto increment column for each table, so maybe you can do a **before_create** on your Rails Model so you can check the last stored record and do a +1 to the invoice column
Check the my edited comment

Comment: @DoeJ Do you have an ID column in addition to your invoice_number column? There's nothing to stop you from using invoice_number in lieu of ID if that would make things clearer for you and your users.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yes, I want to use the invoice_number column, what I wanted to know was how to start from a given number. As a newbie, I didn't realise I could just seed this column... I mark Makarov answer as accepted as it's also working.